# Using {Rows Preceding} for moving average sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, aggregate, window-functions, moving-average

In the following code I'm trying to compute moving average of each month compared to the last 6 months,However SQL is excluding the rows which are null in the denominator for average.

For Example:-

Lets say avg(count(*)) for Sep is 4 and values from March till august are 0.In my code,SQL is taking 4/1 but I need it to include the previous months too even if they have no values (4/6).

```
select [Name],[Report Month]
,avg(count(*))  over (partition by [Name]
                              order by [Report Month]
                              ROWS 5 PRECEDING)
FROM dbo.Sample
group by [Name],[Report Month]
```

As per Tab's suggestion.I tried creating a month table to be left joined with dbo.sample,I'm unfamiliar with creating a month table,Hence I used a online resource,Following is the code.(I'm  using SQLServer2014,It said in the resource,the code is for 2000)

```
CREATE TABLE CalendarMonths (
  date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY (date)
)

DECLARE
  @basedate DATETIME,
  @offset   INT
SELECT
  @basedate = '01 Jan 2000',
  @offset = 1

WHILE (@offset < 2048)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO CalendarMonths SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @offset, date) FROM CalendarMonths
  SELECT @offset = @offset + @offset
END
```

You help is much appreciated!!..Thank you in Advance.

Best,

Comment: Right-join `dbo.Sample` to a month table.

Comment: Hi Tab,Thank you..Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I tried creating a month table but it shows 0 rows affected,Can you please share your query?

Comment: I don't have anything prepared to share.   Edit your post and add your attempt with the month table so we can debug your effort.

Comment: Thank you Tab,I have edited the post with the query I was trying to execute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You got 0 rows affected because you did INSERT...SELECT from an empty table.

It should work if you replace this:

```
 INSERT INTO CalendarMonths SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @offset, date) FROM CalendarMonths
 SELECT @offset = @offset + @offset
```

with this:

```
INSERT INTO CalendarMonths SELECT DATEADD(MONTH, @offset, @basedate)
SET @offset = @offset + 1
```

Then join to this month table on the month and year only, like this:

```
select [Name],cm.[date] AS ReportMonth
,avg(count(*))  over (partition by [Name]
                              order by cm.[date]
                              ROWS 5 PRECEDING)
FROM dbo.Sample s
RIGHT OUTER JOIN CalendarMonths cm
  ON MONTH(s.[Report Month])=MONTH(cm.[date])
  AND YEAR(s.[Report Month])=YEAR(cm.[date])

group by [Name],cm.[date]
```

Comment: That was really helpful Tab,But the calendar month table generated dates with only 1st of every month(01-01,02-01 etc..).The dates in dbo.sample are (01-01,02-02,03-03  etc)..Hence only 1st day of month are showing up..How can I include all dates in a month?

Comment: Excellent Tab!!..With few tweaks based on the requirement I was able to acheive it..Thank you so much for the approach,I would've liked the answer if there was a option..:)

Comment: : )   Actually, in addition to accepting an answer, you can "rate" it up, by clicking the triangle above the number "0" at the top left of the answer.   This is pretty much the equivalent of "liking" it.

Comment: Yepp,I have already done it, but I need to have 15 reputation for the upvotes to appear public..3 more points for me and it will show up..:)